# search text box below the nav bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I am using jquery data tables...
I wanted to move the search text box of the data tables to center of the page and below navigation bar....
the problem is the search text box comes with the data tables plug in so don't know how to move it....
providing my code below...

http://jsfiddle.net/bz2C4/

```
<div class="dataTables_filter" id="vendortable_filter" style="margin-left: 80%;"><label>Search: <input type="text" aria-controls="vendortable"></label></div>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#inventoryTable').dataTable( {
        "bFilter": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        //"bJQueryUI": true,
        "bSort": false,
        "iDisplayLength": 20,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
    } );
    $('.dataTables_length').remove();
    $('.dataTables_info').remove();
    $('.dataTables_filter').css("float", "right");
});
</script>
```

Comment: remove inline css marign-left:80%; form div#vendortable_filter and add text-align:center; [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bz2C4/1/)

Comment: @crazyrohila thanks for your reply...is it possible to move above the vendor list title

Comment: yeah you can do. If you change in html than move this div above vendor div. otherwise you have to do this via position:absolute in css. check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bz2C4/2/).

Comment: but Its not good idea (positioning), so if possible than change in html is better.

Comment: i gave in my actual code database but its not working...can you tell me the reason http://jsfiddle.net/bz2C4/7/

Comment: maybe you have misstyped something in your template (php/html) file. But If you are looking in fiddle than it will not work, because it can not load your custom php (as I think). you should check your code locally.

Comment: @crazyrohila previously i have give u static page...but actually the search text fields are got from js....so in actual code i dont find this tags <div class="dataTables_filter" id="vendortable_filter"><label>Search: <input type="text" aria-controls="vendortable"></label></div>

Answer (score 0):

You can move it using jquery, in not a suggested method but if you can't change the source code is the only way.
Look at something like this

```
$(function() {
  var search = $('.dataTables_filter').detach();
  $('.page-title').before(search);
  var left = ($('.page-title').width() / 2) - (search.width() / 2);
  search.css('margin-left',left+'px');
  search.css('float','');
```

});

Look working here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bz2C4/10/)

Comment: i have given u static page...but actually the search text fields are got from js....so in actual code i dont find this tags <div class="dataTables_filter" id="vendortable_filter"><label>Search: <input type="text" aria-controls="vendortable"></label></div>  actual code  jsfiddle.net/bz2C4/7

Comment: you can use something similar, i used the id, you can use the search filter class that i think always be the same and append the search box always before the title that i think is always there.
Check this out [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bz2C4/8/)

Comment: calculating left margin using the width of the window, in this case i used title div width because is 100% [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bz2C4/10/).